# Solve for a and b of this piecewise function such that the function f(x) is continuous.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, piecewise-continuity

Consider the function defined by

\begin{align*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
ax^{2} + x - b, & x < 2\\
ax+b, & 2\leq x \leq 5\\
2ax - 7, & x > 5.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I was able to find a solution $(a,b)$ for the first two equations, but the solution would not work for the third. It would be amazing if someone could tell me how to find a solution for all three! Thank you!

Comment: Set the functions equal at $2$ and $5$ and solve two equations for two unknowns ($a$ and $b$)

Comment: I don't understand your notation. However, if you want to show the function is continuous, you must have equal lateral limits at critical points.

Comment: a=2, b = 3 makes it work.

Comment: How were you able to find a solution for the first two? What did you do exactly?

Comment: If the piecewise function is continuos then both function has to hit (or approach) the points 2 and 5. So set $ax^2+x-b=ax+b=f(2)$ and likewise for the bottom two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember the definition of continuity:

A function $f$ is continuous at $a$ ($a \in$ Dom$f$) if: $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$$

Also, remember that a limit exists if and only if $$\lim_{x \to a^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x)$$

Now, you want $f$ to be continuous at $x=2$ and at $x=5$, using the preceding definitions at $x=2$:

$$\lim_{x \to 2^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 2^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)=f(2)$$

So, you have the following equality:

$$4a+2-b=2a+b \implies a=b-1$$

Doing the same for $x=5$:

$$\lim_{x \to 5^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 5^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 5}f(x)=f(5)$$

Then, evaluating the lateral limits, you have:

$$5a+b=10a-7 \implies 5a-7=b$$

Remember we obtained $a=b-1$, plugging in the last equation:

$$5a-7=b \implies 5(b-1)-7=b \implies b=3$$

Then $a=b-1 \implies a=3-1=2$.

Therefore, $a=2$ and $b=3$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle f(2) = 2a + b = \lim_{x\rightarrow 2^{-}}f(x) = 4a + 2 -b\\\\
\displaystyle f(5) = 5a + b = \lim_{x\rightarrow 5^{+}}f(x) = 10a - 7
\end{cases}
\end{align*}